I have multiple scenes in one file. How do I change their order in scene-browser?
I'm working on an animation and keep multiple scenes in one file so I can switch quickly. But for convenience, I decided to rename the scene names (in numerical order) so I don't get lost. Can I sort/change the order of the scene names so that I have 1 first, then 2, etc?


rename the scenes 1 and 2 to 01 and 02:

